# How to make PHP form submit with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a form submit an address to run a script.  I am not familiar with code, but trying to wing it here.

So I have one page with this:

```
 <form action="rpr.html" method="post">
Enter Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
<input type="submit">
<input type="hidden" id="my_address_post" value="<?php echo   $_POST['Address']; ?>">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then my second page is saved as rpr.html and here's what I have there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var rprAvmWidgetOptions =
  {
    Token : "222731C6-C794-4BE0-B346-E7AEFF0555E8",
    Query : "address",
    CoBrandCode : "btsremaxontheriver",
    ShowRprLinks : false
  }
  var my_address = 
  document.getElementById('my_address_post').value;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.narrpr.com/widgets/avm-widget/widget.ashx/script"></script>
```

I got this code generated from a website and cannot figure out how to set it up correctly.  I feel like I'm really close, but just not quite there.

Comment: There is no jQuery here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: rprAvmWidgetOptions 
});
```

Found on : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want to use $.ajax() you could just use:

```
$.post(url, rprAvmWidgetOptions);
```